# Facing a difficulty in importhtml function, using order by and select col function but header is also being affected while importing in google sheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath, import, google-query-language

I am using this function
`=QUERY(INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML (I2 & "?refresh=" & I6,I3,I4), "*", )), "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 ORDER BY Col1 ASC")`

This is returning data with the **headers in between the table**.

Also, can we use offset to avoid headers at all, if yes what would be proper syntax
Link to importing page

https://www.ipowatch.in/p/ipo-subscription-numbers-status.html

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#:~:text=Basically%2C%20a%20minimal%20reproducible%20example,run%20on%20the%20given%20dataset

Comment: Could you provide an example sheet so we can check the outcome of what you are trying to do? That way the community can better help you out.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wNmdJ44jfOUauHBfolhJ61-3ZLeHHRkLudVW9ZSSIJw/edit?usp=sharing  this is the sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(INDEX(SUBSTITUTE({
 IMPORTHTML(I2&"?refresh="&I6, I3, I4), 
 IMPORTHTML(I2&"?refresh="&I6, I3, I5)}, "*", )), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col6,Col7 order by Col1", 1)
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JIiqmTrAZpkbaLcCp1QU3RZdowhm1iVrJLuc04DUCZU/edit#gid=0)

Comment: select col is still missing in this, need to select 2 out of 4 columns

Comment: either the order by or select column is working, need to use both at once

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wNmdJ44jfOUauHBfolhJ61-3ZLeHHRkLudVW9ZSSIJw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @VishalChaudhary answer updated. see the pink cell

Comment: It was new that we can import two tables all together. thankyou